# Can i install / use nuget if my documents folder is on a shared drive?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I see a [number of issues](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/240739) on the nuget forum around not being able to install if your My documents folder is on a shared drive.  If I don't have the flexibility to change this (locked down policy) is there any way i can use nuget?

Here is the error i get when trying to install it from the VS Extension Manager:

**The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT:**

[image]

The VS log file shows:

```
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - Microsoft Visual Studio Extension Installer
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - -------------------------------------------
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - Initializing Install...
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - Extension Details...
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Identifier      : NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Name            : NuGet Package Manager
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Author          : Microsoft Corporation
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Version         : 1.6.21215.9133
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Description     : A collection of tools to automate the process of downloading, installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing packages from a VS Project.
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Locale          : en-US
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  MoreInfoURL     : http://docs.nuget.org/
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  InstalledByMSI  : False
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  MinFramework    : 4.0
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  MaxFramework    : 4.0
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Supported Visual Studio Editions : 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -      Version : 10.0
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          Pro
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          IntegratedShell
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          VWDExpress
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          VPDExpress
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -      Version : 11.0
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          Pro
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          IntegratedShell
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          VWDExpress
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -          VPDExpress
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  Supported Isolated Shells : 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM -  References      : 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - 
3/23/2012 9:45:26 PM - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String applicationPath, String suffixOrName, Boolean isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String applicationPath)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManager(SupportedVSSKU sku)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManagerForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1 applicableSKUs)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

Comment: What additional information you can see in `%TEMP%\VSIXInstaller_<GUID>.log`?

Comment: @Oleg - I dumped the log file into the question

Answer (score 10):

I was facing a similar issue and the various suggestions about `CasPol` and `loadFromRemoteSources` failed; here's what worked for me (on Windows 7 sp1):

1. Uninstall the current NuGet extension
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Open up a registry editor and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT-USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\`

   - The `Personal` key will show the shared folder as its value
4. Amend that value to a local drive location, e.g. `C:\Temp\`

   - Don't close `regedit` as you'll be changing it back in a moment
5. Open Visual Studio

   - it might complain about not finding certain settings, but I just clicked through the warnings
6. Install the NuGet extension

   - at least for me, this all happened smoothly in exactly the way that wasn't happening before
7. Quit Visual Studio
8. Revert the `Personal` registry value back to its previous state
9. Restart Visual Studio

   - *... et voilà!*

Comment: Agreed, this is the solution indeed. Well done, this worked amazingly. There is some indication that this has to do with the VSIXInstaller.exe and not the NuGet Package Manager. The issue is that for some reason, the VSIXInstaller is looking for your Personal\MyDocuments folder and if it is usually mapped to a network drive and it is not currently mapped it will fail. Here is a codeplex issue that can be referenced. https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/700

Comment: Oleg's solution was much easier, just adding this to the devenv.exe.config under configuration/runtime works just as well: <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>

Comment: what if the personal tag just says %USERPROFILE%\Documents?

I don't see my mapped v-drive listed, I'm working on a related but not identical problem..

Answer (score 3):

I don't tested this myself, but you can try to modify `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` file and include [loadFromRemoteSources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252%28VS.100%29.aspx) element:

```xml
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
```

at the location `<configuration>` \ `<runtime>`. Additionally you can try to verify that no other old version NuGet is installed. You should start Visual Studio 2010 shortcut with context menu and choose "Run as administrator" to be sure that you can uninstall it.

Additionally you can consider to add "FullTrust" to the share for the .NET

```
CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -url file://ServerName/ShareName/* FullTrust
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your Environment Variable Path in the MyComputer's System Properties > Advance tab

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know NuGet installs under "My Documents" is the following:

```
%LocalAppData\NuGet <-- here you usually find the default cache folder

%AppData\NuGet <-- here you find the machine-level nuget.config file
```

Can you check if these folders are there?

Just a theory, but if not, maybe you can create those folders yourself and retry the installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have redirected folders.... then something is borked.

Workaround:

Choose menu *Start* → *All Programs* → *Accessories*, right-click on Command Prompt, and choose *Run As Administrator*. Type `subst Z: "C:\Windows"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Z is your redirected folder path).

Run your stuff again.

The "fix": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886549